# GLSurfaceView goes black if i add another view

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es-2.0

I am attempting to add android widget like android.widget.Button on top of my GLSurfaceView. However if i do this, GLSurfaceView gets completely black

Here is the code i use to do such thing:

```
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Hello World");
    setContentView(mGLView);
    addContentView(b, new LayoutParams(60, 60));//comenting this 
    //line makes GLSurfaceView work as expected
```

I also tried having them both on a layout and the same problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by commenting this line of code

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); << this line
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public boolean touchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if (mRenderer.scene != null) {
            mRenderer.scene.control.onTouchEvent(e);
            mRenderer.scene.onTouchEvent(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```